# Verilog - range handling with named values

Tags: verilog

I have assigned names to numbers using:

```
`define ADD 0
`define SUB 1
`define LSF 2
`define RSF 3
`define AND 4
`define OR 5
```

I'd like to handle in a     `case` block such that the code will apply for more than one option.
In C this can be done using:

```
switch (x){

case ADD:
case SUB:
case LSF:
case RSF:
case AND:
case OR:
    printf ("Handling");
    break;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve that in Verilog?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, commas!

```
case (x)
ADD, SUB, LSF, RSF, AND, OR: begin
    $display("Handling multiple cases");
    // no need for breaks
end
MULT: begin
    $display("handle a single case");
end
default: begin
    $display("do something to do for all other cases");
end
endcase
```